# Reclaim unused oracle lob space "non lob data"

Tags: oracle11g

Friends...

DB: Oracle 11gR2

OS: Linux

I have this lob segment (basic file, non assm) which is occupying 100 GB of storage, I queried "dba_extents", dbms_lob.getlength(lob_col) and find out

```
Total storage occupied: 100 GB

Lob Data: 70 GB

non Lob Data (storage - lob data): 30 GB
```

As per oracle metalink 386341.1, it says non lob data can be both free space and/or undo space since lob segments stores undo data under lob segment space so it's hard to find there is any available free space or just undo segments.

Questions:

1. How to exactly find how much free space can be reclaimed once we shrink table with move tablespace command?
2. Can I assume "non LOB DATA" as the current free space and same will be recovered once segment will be shrinked?

With about #2, what happens if developers purge some table lob and to perform that it will request more undo from the database which will be eventually become free and this exercise of reclaim space won't be worth.

```
output of dbms_space.unused_space
=================================
total block : 11900000
total bytes : 102208345855
unused blocks: 0
unused bytes : 0
last used extent file id : 345
last used extent block id: 856800
last used block: 8192
```

Basically my target is to reclaim all available space from the lob column.

Answer (score 0):

Before you alter the table, check the size of the table from dba_segments and check the size after you execute the below syntax in order to know how much space you have reclaimed.

Syntax used to reclaim LOB space is:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY LOB (<lob_column>) (SHRINK SPACE);
```

This will also help you to reclaim the space.

```
ALTER TABLE test MOVE LOB(image) STORE AS ( TABLESPACE lob_dat1 ) 
/
```

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LOBs/LOBS_85.shtml

Answer (score 0):

For future refrerence .Another thing which could be done in such a case is that we can shrink the corresponding table of the LOB.

First we can find the corresponding table of a LOB of particular  by running the below query

```
  select  a.table_name,  a.segment_name , b.bytes/1024/1024 from dba_lobs a, dba_segments b where a.segment_name = b.segment_name and a.owner = b.owner and b.segment_name=<LOB_NAME>;
```

Then using the tablename from the above query we can shrink the table using

```
Alter table <TABLE_NAME> enable row movement;
Alter table <TABLE_NAME> shrink space cascade;
Alter table <TABLE_NAME> disable row movement;
```

This shall shrink the table and the corresponding LOB of the table to reclaim the unused space.